# Simple Encryption for Strings

Tags: c++, c++11, caesar-cipher

I have written this code for practice. Here we will enter the number by which we want to shift alphabets.
For eg.

> Enter by how many numbers you want to shift alphabets: 4
>
> Enter string: Programmer C++
>
> Encrypted String: Lnkcnwiian Y++
>
> Decryted String: Programmer C++

Review this code and suggest better C++11 and C++14 alternatives.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Cipher
{
    unsigned n;
    const std::vector<char> alphabetL { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
      'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W',
      'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    const std::vector<char> alphabetS { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
      'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
      'x', 'y', 'z' };
    std::unordered_map<char, char> shiftByNL;
    std::unordered_map<char, char> shiftByNS;

  public:
    Cipher(unsigned n = 0);
    std::string encrypt(std::string&);
    std::string decrypt(std::string&);

  private:
    char byValue(const char); //Find by value
};

Cipher::Cipher(unsigned n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        shiftByNL.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetL[i], alphabetL[(26 - n) + i]));
        shiftByNS.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetS[i], alphabetS[(26 - n) + i]));
    }
    for (int i = n; i < 26; i++)
    {
        shiftByNL.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetL[i], alphabetL[i - n]));
        shiftByNS.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetS[i], alphabetS[i - n]));
    }
}

char Cipher::byValue(const char value)
{
    for (auto itL = shiftByNL.begin(), itS = shiftByNS.begin();
          itL != shiftByNL.end(), itS != shiftByNS.end(); ++itL, ++itS)
    {
        if (itL->second == value)
        {
            return itL->first;
        }
        else if (itS->second == value)
        {
            return itS->first;
        }
    }
    //not an alphabet
    return value;
}

std::string Cipher::encrypt(std::string& original)
{
    std::string encrypted;
    std::size_t len = original.length();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (original[i] == ' ')
        {
            encrypted = encrypted + ' ';
        }
        else if (shiftByNS.find(original[i]) != shiftByNS.end())
        {
            auto search = shiftByNS.find(original[i]);
            encrypted = encrypted + search->second;
        }
        else if (shiftByNL.find(original[i]) != shiftByNL.end())
        {
            auto search = shiftByNL.find(original[i]);
            encrypted = encrypted + search->second;
        }
        else //not an alphabet
        {
            encrypted = encrypted + original[i];
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}

std::string Cipher::decrypt(std::string& encrypted)
{
    std::string decrypted;
    std::size_t len = encrypted.length();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (encrypted[i] == ' ')
        {
            decrypted = decrypted + ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            char key = byValue(encrypted[i]);
            decrypted = decrypted + key;
        }
    }
    return decrypted;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned num;
    std::cout << "Enter by how many numbers you want to shift alphabets: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cin.ignore();
    Cipher cipher(num);
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::string res = cipher.encrypt(str);
    std::cout << "Encrypted String: ";
    std::cout << res << '\n';
    std::cout << "Decryted String: ";
    std::string decrypted = cipher.decrypt(res);
    std::cout << decrypted << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you should hard-code the length of alphabet as `26` here:

```
for (int i = n; i < 26; i++)
```

Doing so will make it harder to adapt this code to languages with a different number of letters.  Instead, prefer to use `alphabetL.size()` and `alphabetS.size()` (and probably use separate loops, as some languages don't have the same number of upper-case and lower-case letters).

---

It's probably advisable to test that `n` is less than the alphabet length (or to reduce it modulo length before using), and perhaps reject a zero shift (which is what we call a "weak key" for this cipher).

---

`decrypt()` is much slower than `encrypt`, because it does a *search* for every character.  What you really want is a pair of maps, but not lowercase and uppercase - instead you want forward and reverse (with both upper and lower in the same map).  In fact, I'd go further; allow negative values for the shift, and then we can create a separate `Cipher` object for the decryption.

---

Constructor that can accept a single argument should be `explicit`.  I don't think a default of `0` is a good choice (see my comment about weak keys).  Also, prefer initialization to assignment in constructors (GCC will warn, with `-Weffc++`).

---

`Cipher::n` is never initialized or used - we can drop that member.  Also, the two constant vectors don't need to be members - they are used only in the constructor, where they can be shared between all instances.  We can simplify further by making them string literals.

---

`encrypt()` and `decrypt()` both take a *modifiable* reference to their input, but it seems they should not modify the input string.  You could pass a reference to `const` string, but I think it might be easier to accept a copy by value, and modify the copy.

Also, they shouldn't be modifying the `Cipher` object, so they can be declared `const`.

---

## Modified code

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

class Cipher
{
    const std::unordered_map<char, char> map;

public:
    explicit Cipher(int n);
    std::string encrypt(std::string) const;

private:
    static std::unordered_map<char, char> make_map(int n);
};


Cipher::Cipher(int n)
    : map{make_map(n)}
{}

std::unordered_map<char, char> Cipher::make_map(int n)
{
    // helper function to give a positive value for a%b
    auto mod = [](int a, int b){ a %= b; return a < 0 ? a + b : a; };

    std::unordered_map<char, char> map;
    {
        static const char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int const m = sizeof alphabet - 1; // subtract the final NUL
        for (int i = 0;  i < m;  ++i) {
            map.insert(std::make_pair(alphabet[i], alphabet[mod(i+n,m)]));
        }
    }
    {
        static const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int const m = sizeof alphabet - 1; // subtract the final NUL
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            map.insert(std::make_pair(alphabet[i], alphabet[mod(i+n,m)]));
        }
    }

    return map;
}

std::string Cipher::encrypt(std::string s) const
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                   [=](char c){ auto it = map.find(c); return it == map.end() ? c : it->second; });
    return s;
}
```

I slightly modified the test program to allow it to accept command-line arguments (easier for test scripts):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int num;
    if (argc > 1) {
        char* pos;
        num = std::strtol(argv[1], &pos, 0);
        if (*pos || pos == argv[1]) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " NUM WORD" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Enter by how many numbers you want to shift alphabets: ";
        std::cin >> num;
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    Cipher cipher(num);
    Cipher decipher(-num);

    std::string str;
    if (argc > 2) {
        str = argv[2];
    } else {
        std::cout << "Enter string: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
    }

    std::string res = cipher.encrypt(str);
    std::string decrypted = decipher.encrypt(res);
    std::cout << "Encrypted String: "
              << res << '\n'
              << "Decrypted String: "
              << decrypted << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

While I agree with the general idea of most of what Toby Speight says, for this case, I'd tend to avoid using a map, and instead just use a contiguous table, something on this general order:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <limits>

class encrypt { 
    std::array<char, std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()> table;
public:
    encrypt(int shift) { 
        std::iota(table.begin(), table.end(), 0);
        std::rotate(&table['A'], &table['Z'+1] - shift, &table['Z'+1]);
        std::rotate(&table['a'], &table['z'+1] - shift, &table['z'+1]);
    }

    char operator()(char in) const { return table[in]; }

    std::string &operator()(std::string &in) const {
        for (char &c : in)
            c = table[(unsigned char )c];
    }
};

class decrypt {
    std::array<char, std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()> table;
public:
    decrypt(int shift) {        
        std::iota(table.begin(), table.end(), 0);        
        std::rotate(&table['A'], &table['A'] + shift, &table['Z'+1]);
        std::rotate(&table['a'], &table['a'] + shift, &table['z'+1]);
    }

    char operator()(char in) const { return table[in]; }

    std::string &operator()(std::string &in) const {
        for (char &c : in)
            c = table[(unsigned char)c];
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::string input = "Programmer C++";

    encrypt(4)(input);

    std::cout << input << "\n";

    decrypt(4)(input);

    std::cout << input << "\n";

}
```

As long as we're only dealing with a 256-character set, this seems perfectly reasonable (at least to me). If we wanted to deal with Unicode, Toby's would almost certainly be the preferred approach though.

Note: the `main` I've included is not intended as a suggestion of how `main` should work. It's really just enough to test that the rest of the code works as intended.

Comment: Yes, a simple table makes much more sense than a map - I didn't see the wood for the trees!  Oh, and I like the use of `std::rotate()` - that's an `<algorithm>` I'd almost forgotten exists.  (But note that it only works for character codings with contiguous letters - certainly not EBCDIC, nor for Latin-1 if we want to support alphabets such as Swedish).

Answer (score 6):

```
Cipher::Cipher(unsigned n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        shiftByNL.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetL[i], alphabetL[(26 - n) + i]));
        shiftByNS.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetS[i], alphabetS[(26 - n) + i]));
    }
    for (int i = n; i < 26; i++)
    {
        shiftByNL.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetL[i], alphabetL[i - n]));
        shiftByNS.insert(std::make_pair(alphabetS[i], alphabetS[i - n]));
    }
}
```

The first loop has a signed-to-unsigned comparison.

Should the user be able to map the letter A to the letter B using -1? Does `n` have to be `unsigned`?

The user that calls `std::vector<T>::operator[]` needs to ensure the index is in range. What happens if `n` is larger than the alphabet size?

---

```
char Cipher::byValue(const char value)
{
    for (auto itL = shiftByNL.begin(), itS = shiftByNS.begin();
          itL != shiftByNL.end(), itS != shiftByNS.end(); ++itL, ++itS)
    {
        if (itL->second == value)
        {
            return itL->first;
        }
        else if (itS->second == value)
        {
            return itS->first;
        }
    }
    //not an alphabet
    return value;
}
```

Your search traverses both the upper and lower case maps.  We know if `value` is upper or lower, so we can decide which container we want to search.

Know your algorithms! If you want to linearly search a container, use `std::find`/`std::find_if`.  For the latter, you can use a predicate that searches member second of the pairs.

```
char Cipher::byValue(const char value)
{
    if (std::isupper(value)) {
        auto found = std::find_if(shiftByNL.begin(), shiftByNL.end(), mapped_second(value));
        return found != shiftByNL.end() ? found->first : value;
    }
    auto found = std::find(shiftByNS.begin(), shiftByNS.end(), mapped_second(value));
    return found != shiftByNS.end() ? found->first : value;
}
```

From here, you can DRY it up into a higher abstraction.

---

```
std::string Cipher::encrypt(std::string& original)
{
    std::string encrypted;
    std::size_t len = original.length();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (original[i] == ' ')
        {
            encrypted = encrypted + ' ';
        }
        else if (shiftByNS.find(original[i]) != shiftByNS.end())
        {
            auto search = shiftByNS.find(original[i]);
            encrypted = encrypted + search->second;
        }
        else if (shiftByNL.find(original[i]) != shiftByNL.end())
        {
            auto search = shiftByNL.find(original[i]);
            encrypted = encrypted + search->second;
        }
        else //not an alphabet
        {
            encrypted = encrypted + original[i];
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

`original` is not modified, so qualify it with `const`.

Consider reserving the `encrypted` string capacity.

Since you aren't using the index for anything besides container access, use the range-based for loop (or an algorithm like `std::transform`).

---

```
std::cin >> num;
```

If `std::cin` fails to read an unsigned value, the value that is assigned to `num` is `0`.  Check to make sure the value was correctly read from the stream.

---

Consider a policy based approach if you plan to support more than just ASCII.  If you plan to stick with only ASCII, consider using a mathematical approach rather than multiple lookup tables.

Leverage the type system to provide information for the user. Phantom types can wrap its payload with tags like encrypted and unencrypted.

```
template <typename T>
struct string_data {
    explicit StringData(std::string const& input) : data{input} {}
    std::string data;
};

struct encrypted {};
struct unencrypted {};

class cipher {
    // ...
    string_data<encrypted> encrypt(string_data<unencrypted> const& data);
    string_data<unencrypted> decrypt(string_data<encrypted> const& data);
};
```